# Deploying and loading iframe on same localhost as react.js app

Tags: reactjs, iframe, widget

I have a react.js app which is basically a website running on localhost:8080. Now I created a second app which is a webchat-assistant and executed "npm script-run build" to create a build. I want to embed the build of webchat assistant into the website with a iframe-tag on the index.html of the website.

I have the following 3 files from the build:
`/public/build/static/js/787.4ed02641.chunk.js.map`
`/public/build/static/js/main.0a7f35ef.js.map`
`/public/build/static/js/787.4ed02641.chunk.js`
`/public/build/static/js/main.0a7f35ef.js`

and the following tags from the index.html of the webchat build
`<script defer="defer" src="/public/build/static/js/main.0a7f35ef.js"></script>` 
`<link href="public/build/static/css/main.b8e6b54b.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Now I dont know how to proceed

Is there a way to host both apps on localhost:8080?

Thank you in advance
KR.

I tried to copy and paste the  into the website but its not working